# Dynamic Types within a Relational Model using Object-Role-Modeling (ORM)

Tags: database, relational, database-design, object-role-modeling

In Object Role Modeling (ORM), given an entity of **thing** that had a relationship to an entity of **type** and where the type entity can be specified to live and the thing entity could have a value for date of birth, how would I specify a constraint that would exclude instances of thing from having a value for date of birth if the instance of type associated with thing was not set to live. See Diagram Below...

[ORM Diagram of Model to be constrained http://img197.imageshack.us/img197/6551/dynamictypeorm.jpg](http://img197.imageshack.us/img197/6551/dynamictypeorm.jpg)

The purpose behind my questions is to allow for the modeling of types within a system when it is unclear what the types will be, but characteristics of the types are known. Your answers do not need to be in terms of ORM if you feel there is a more applicable approach. Thanks for reading, hopefully you can help me.

Comment: I think the answer might have something to do with Set-Comparison Constraints Involving Joins which is covered in this paper by Terry Halpin http://www.orm.net/pdf/JoinConstraints.pdf

Comment: The material in that paper is covered in updated form, in "The Book". See my edit, below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The book that John Sanders has recommended is one of the best books I have ever read.  Also, all your ORM questions can most likely be answered through a reading of it.

To directly answer you question though, (and sidestep any questions of the validity of the model), there are two obvious ways I see to constrain it as is.

We could use either a subset constraint or an equality constraint, depending on what it is you actually want to capture.

Assigning an equality constraint (Right) between the roles, we can generate a constraint that would conceptually require that any Thing of a living Type has a date of birth and that any Thing with a date of birth be of a living Type.

Assigning a Subset constraint (Left) between the roles, we can constrain the model such that any Thing of a Type with a DateOfBirth must be of a Type that is living.  This, unlike the equality constraint will allow for things to be of a living type, but not have a date of birth.

[image]

**additions:**
To create these types of subset and equality constraints that will work, we need to use something called a ['Join Path'](http://www.orm.net/pdf/orm-jcm7.pdf).  Using a join path, we can create a Join-Subset Constraint and Join-Equality constraint that will span multiple roles on both sides of the constraint.  [Examples](http://www.objectrolemodeling.com/WebLog/tabid/58/EntryId/40/Join-Path-Subset-Constraints.aspx) of join paths can at times be obvious and easy to follow. but can also get a little [overwhelming](https://www.ormfoundation.org/forums/p/589/1779.aspx) and complex at times. Also of note, is that although NORMA does support creating join paths, in equality, subset, and exclusion constraints the verbilazation is not 100% complete for them, as explained [here](https://www.ormfoundation.org/forums/p/589/1779.aspx).  This is also one of the reasons why it is easier to use Subsets at current, since it is easier to validate the correctness of the model conceptually.

To create a Join Path in NORMA when assigning the roles for a Subset, Equality, or Exclusion constraint first assign all roles that are part of a path with a single click, and then double click to move on to the next path.  When the constraint is capable of join paths, the Roles involved in that constraint will be labeled [#.#] instead of just [#].  So when we are creating our constraints we can say here that roles [1.1]&[1.2] are a subset/equal to roles [2.1]/[2.1].  Note that the Facts playing a part in each role must also match.  So he we get a verbalization from NORMA:
If some Thing has some DateOfBirth; some Thing is of some Type then that Thing is of some Type; that Type is living.
Which is better stated as: If some Thing of some Type has some DateOfBirth; then that Type is living.

[image]

However, there is a third (and preferable) way that we could constrain this, which would be subtyping.  Since things that are alive, and things that aren't alive are very different, we probably don't want to be mapping them to the same tables anyway.  Here we split our Type fact into two subtypes, OrganicTypes and NonOrganicTypes.  The Exclusive Or constraint between the two subtypes tells us that every type is either Organic or NonOrganic.  and the Note tells us the Derivation Rule that we use for determining which group a type belongs to.
From there, we redefine our [Thing is of Type] role to [LivingThing is of OrganicType].  and since OrganicThings by deffinition are capable of life, our constraint for DOB/is living is now built into the model.

[image]

Comment: I can't get NORMA to like either of your first two models. Could you edit the answer to include the verbalization of the subset and equality constraints? Also, more importantly, could you post how you got that to align so nicely? ;-)

Comment: When you have any elements of an ORM model selected in NORMA a 'Format' menu item appears.  The hot keys are also, useful, ALT+O+A+C to center elements vertically, ALT+O+A+M to center elements horizontally.
I'll also edit my post to explain the join paths that I used in the first half.

Comment: Also, when dragging elements or roles, hold shift as it will force the elements to move along their current X/Y axis.

Comment: Ah ha, You nailed it! Kudos to you! I do have the book, working my way through it. One of my favs too. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there's more than one problem with your model, even as simple as it is. A thing may have a date of birth if it was *ever* living. It may once have been living, yet now be dead.

Also, you'll want to clarify whether the absence of the fact "Type lives" implies "Type does not live" (Closed World Assumption), or whether it only implies "Type is not known to live" (Open World Assumption, I think).

One additional concern I have is that your question seems to be somewhat confused, combining "relational model" and "ORM" in the same "sentence". Object-Role Modeling is a Conceptual modeling tool for creating conceptual models, which may then be mapped to a Relational schema. Even if you are reverse-engineering an existing Relational schema, it's best to use the schema as only part of the information you would use to create a correct Conceptual model. In addition, use examples of valid input and output, and also discussions with the domain experts. This will often help you discover important constraints which were not captured by the Relational schema, or which may have been captured incorrectly.

---

BTW, for an excellent ORM tool, see [NORMA](http://www.ormfoundation.org/files/folders/norma_the_software/default.aspx). It's an add-in to Visual Studio 2005 or 2008 (Standard Edition or above), and uses the modern ORM2 notation. It can generate SQL for several different databases, as well as ER diagrams and even code.

---

Also, see The Book:
[image]

Comment: This is my fear, that the model is open to interpretation based on ones understanding of the words used to describe it rather than those words being defined based on the relationships within the model. If I were able to specify what I am asking the only way to interpret the model would be that only an instance of thing with type that lives could have a dob, implying the lives refers to the fact that thing lives not that it's currently alive. Of coarse if that was the case I would probably want it to be required based on the state of lives which creates a whole nother issue :( Thanks

Comment: One thing about conceptual models is that they do better when working with real concepts. You seem to have abstracted a set of situations in order to get an answer that could apply to all of the situations. I recommend you work with one model that's more concrete, and come up with a solution for the more-concrete model. The tools of conceptual modeling will help you make that concrete model correct.

Comment: I agree that less abstract types would be ideal, but in situations where they may be unobtainable I hope there is still a way to finish an applicable design. I thought about it a little and I propose that the only domains that can't be modeled conceptually are one that conflicts with themselves. In this case my goal no matter how lazy one has to be to want to achieve it should still be realistic.

Comment: I guess I just haven't had experience doing conceptual models where the concepts could not be clarified or conflicted with each other. I would think it impossible to create a valid model if the model is not understood.

Comment: It might also be interesting (if painful) to see the answer your question would receive at http://www.ormfoundation.org/forums/84.aspx or http://www.ormfoundation.org/forums/10.aspx.

Comment: Impossible may very well be the answer even if only from a standpoint of practicality and if so you have done a fine job answering my question and I thank you and everyone else for sharing your knowledge with me.

Comment: The answer may be "impossible", or it's possible that the readers of that forum have a lot of experience in modeling, and may recognize your situation. They may be able to tell you how they've solved this problem (lack of specificity) in the past. As I've said, I haven't had this problem before, so can't really help with it.

Comment: I actually hadn't seen you message about the forum yet when I left my last comment. I will check over there for sure, thanks.

Comment: 2019 Update: NORMA is now available for Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition.http://www.ormfoundation.org/

Answer (score 0):

ORM (and [domain model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_model)) as I understand them are both [conceptual model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conceptual_model_%28computer_science%29), which are used to analyze the business domain, instead of designing solutions. At this layer, bringing in concepts like "types" or "dynamic types" are too early, and does not suit the purpose of the model.

From [Object Role Modeling: An Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290383.aspx)

[alt text http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Aa290383.dv_vsea_ormoverview_06%28en-us,VS.71%29.gif](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Aa290383.dv_vsea_ormoverview_06%28en-us,VS.71%29.gif)

You can put an equality constraint (a dotted line with a circled “=” symbol) between "is alive" and "has date of birth." Similar to the "is tenured" and "is contracted till."

Comment: My intention is to help clarify the business domain. But to be effective at doing so shouldn't ORM allow me to state that a thing can only have a dob if it lives? If I were to validate the diagram from my question with a business user they would be unaware that my intentions are to only allow things with types that live to have a DOB.

Comment: @eed3si9n: That's not a close analogy, since both roles are played by the same entity in your example, but not in his example.

Answer (score 0):

In a database context, assuming that you have three separate tables, I would create a function that counts the number of rows in a join between the entity and its type.  Use this function in the table holding the DOB to ensure that the DOB is null or the count is 1.

Pseudo-code:

```
 function fn_count_living(id)
     declare @count int
     select @count = count(*)
     from entities inner join types on entities.typeid = types.id
     where entities.id = id and types.living = 1
     return @count
 end
```

Constraint

```
 fn_count_living(entity_id) = 1 or dob is null
```